# load data to my swift app via Alamofire (i have installed it)

Tags: sql, swift, alamofire

i have installed Alamofire into my swift app. i have 2 tables into phpMyAdmin and i want to retrieve data. in my project all the tables are dynamic in order to be able to connect them easily. can you help me connect it to phpMyAdmin, like where to put password and ID and how to get data from server and make it load to my application

Comment: Please review [guidelines for asking questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in order to get a quality answer.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot connect to `phpMyAdmin` via an iOS app unless you create a php api which interacts with these tables and execute a select statement or insert based on the data received. You should setup a `php` script which retrieves `GET` OR `POST` variables and then uses those variables to execute an action.

**PHP script**

```
<?php
$param1 = $_GET["data"];
//do something with your data and your database
echo "data received or something";
?>
```

**Alamofire request**

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://yourserverurl", parameters: ["data": "myourdatahere"])
         .response { request, response, data, error in
             print(request)
             print(response)
             print(data)
             print(error)
}
```

Comment: yes but where i have to put phpMyAdmin Password and id in order to be able to log in and retrieve data??

Comment: You should do that in your php script.

Comment: No problem, hope this helps :)